# AWS API Gateway Custom Authorizer lambda is not triggering

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to implement Basic authentication, using this article as inspiration:

https://medium.com/@Da_vidgf/http-basic-auth-with-api-gateway-and-serverless-5ae14ad0a270

The application sets up as described:

- WWW-Authenticate in the 401 response
- Request Authorizer set up in the Authorizer section
- Tie the authorizer to my endpoint, on the ANY method execution

I can test my custom authorizer using the `Test` feature under `Authorizers` successfully but when I call the API using curl (or anything else) there is no authentication.  The authorizer lambda doesn't get called and there are no logs in CloudWatch.

Any idea where I could look next?

Comment: Are you caching the token? Create a new token, then do your curl before any other test and see if the authorizer lambda fires then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to deploy API Gateway to apply settings before test.

Comment: This was it.  Just need to go to `Resources->Actions->Deploy API` menu item.